# LibreNMS Nginx php5-fpm text pages with no style - rewrite woking?

Tags: php, nginx

During the install the wizard showed font/page style fine, but now when I go to `http://whateverhostname/index.php` it just shows unformatted text where all the links should be, and broken image links. It seems like the rewrite isn't working right, where should I be looking?

Comment: Zero information provided required to help you. Zero. You could have at least pasted the config file, but no, there's exactly ZERO info in your question. But, here you go - nginx doesn't work like crapache. It proxies the request to an endpoint. That endpoint, when PHP is in question, is called `php-fpm`. You haven't set that up. Now  you are stuck with Apache, the shittiest server ever made. I'd feel sorry for you but.. zero freakin' info provided when asking for help.. unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

I never got Nginx working, but switched to Apache2.4 and got it working in 10 minutes.